# Laravel: Feature Test fails because of added middleware

Tags: laravel, phpunit

After a user signs up and verifies their email, they must complete their signup with additional information. This happens at `/register/complete-signup`

The issue makes absolutely no sense to me.

For whatever reason, when I added my Middleware `has-not-completed-signup`, the test starts failing because a App\User no longer has the associated App\Account which is happening in the controller via `attach()`

**As soon as I remove my middleware from the route, it works fine.**

My middleware is there to prevent a user who has completed the signup already from visiting or POSTing to those routes. I tested in the browser and the redirect works. The controller method is being used in the test and i can `dd($account->users)` and get the correct response. But if I do `$user->accounts`, the collection is empty.

Once I remove my middleware, `$user->accounts` is no longer empty. But I did a `dd()` inside my middleware and it's not even running (which is correct because the user doesn't have an account).

So why would this make it fail? I'm completely lost.

I tried to include all relevant information below. If there is something else you need, please let me know.

Edit:

In my middleware, I've commented out the functionality. Something about checking an eloquent relationship makes me test fail. I have no idea why.

This makes the test fail:

```
if (!auth()->user()->accounts->isEmpty()) {      
  //return redirect(RouteServiceProvider::HOME);
}
```

If for example I change it to something useless like this, it works:

```
if (auth()->user()) {
//return redirect(RouteServiceProvider::HOME);
}
```

I can do `$account->users` , but `$user->accounts` returns empty collection on the controller when I use my middleware

---

Original:

Here are my routes:

```
// auth scaffolding
Auth::routes(['verify' => true]);

// main app routes
Route::middleware('verified', 'auth')->group(function() {

    // User verified and has an App\Account
    Route::middleware('completed-signup')->group(function() {
        Route::get("/", 'HomeController@index' )->name('home');
        Route::get('/paywall', 'BillingController@paywall')->name('paywall');

    });

    // The user hasn't attached an App\Account to their User
    Route::middleware('has-not-completed-signup')->group(function() {
        Route::get("/register/complete-signup", 'AccountController@showCompleteSignup' )->name('complete-signup');
        Route::post('/register/complete-signup', 'AccountController@storeCompleteSignup')->name('complete-signup.store');
    });

});
```

`has-not-completed-signup` Middleware:

```
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if (auth()->user()->hasCompletedAccountSetup()) {

            return redirect(RouteServiceProvider::HOME);
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
```

App/User method:

```
Class User extends Authenticatable implements MustVerifyEmail { 
...

    public function accounts() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Account', 'account_role_user')->withPivot('role_id');
    }
    public function hasCompletedAccountSetup() {
        return !$this->accounts->isEmpty();
    }
    ...
```

AccountController@storeCompletedSignup:

```
    public function storeCompleteSignup(Request $request) {

        $validatedData = $request->validate([
            'company' => 'required|max:255',
            'contact_state' => 'required|max:255',
            'contact_country' => 'required|max:255',
            'contact_zip' => 'required|max:255',
            'contact_city' => 'required|max:255',
            'contact_phone' => 'nullable|max:255',
            'contact_address_1' => 'required|max:255',
            'contact_address_2' => 'nullable|max:255',
            'contact_first_name' => 'required',
            'contact_last_name' => 'required',
            'contact_email' => 'required'
        ]);

        $user = auth()->user();

        $account = new Account($validatedData);

        $account->contact_first_name = $user->first_name;
        $account->contact_last_name = $user->last_name;
        $account->contact_email = $user->email;

        $account->save();



        $account->users()->attach(
            $user->id, 
            ['role_id' => Role::where('name', 'owner')->first()->id ]
        );

        return $request->wantsJson()
                    ? new Response('Signup Completed Successfully', 201)
                    : redirect()->route('/');

    }
```

My Test:

```
    /**
     * @test
     */
    public function a_user_can_complete_signup()
    {


        $user = Factory('App\User')->create();
        $this->actingAs($user);

        $accountAttributes = factory('App\Account')->raw([
            'contact_first_name' => "TEST",
            'contact_last_name' => $user->last_name,
            'contact_email' => $user->email,
            'contact_country' => "USA"
        ]);

        $res = $this->post('/register/complete-signup', $accountAttributes);

        $res->assertSessionDoesntHaveErrors();

        $this->assertTrue( !$user->accounts->isEmpty() ); // THIS FAILS
        $this->assertTrue( $user->accounts->first()->company == $accountAttributes['company']);
        $this->assertTrue( $user->accounts->first()->contact_first_name == $user->first_name );


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue wasn't actually with the middleware, but it was because I had to refresh the model after the POST on the test.

`$this->assertTrue( !$user->accounts->isEmpty() );`

needed to become

`$this->assertTrue( !$user->fresh()->accounts->isEmpty() );`

which passed the test.

I knew about the `fresh` and `refresh()` methods, but the middleware causing the issue didn't make sense to me.